# Computing the Fourier transform of $e^{-|x|}$

Tags: fourier-analysis

I'm trying to compute the Fourier Transform of $e^{-|x|}$ however I receive a different answer than wolfram alpha. Wolfram Alpha gets $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{1}{1+\varepsilon^2}$ and I get $\frac{2}{1+\varepsilon^2}$. I'll illustrate my working below:

$$F_{x \rightarrow t}(e^{-|x|})=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i\varepsilon x} \cdot e^{-|x|} dx=\int_0^{\infty}e^{x(i\varepsilon -1)}dx+\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{x(i\varepsilon +1)} dx $$ And since $$e^{i\varepsilon x}e^{-x}\leq\left | e^{i \varepsilon x}\right| \cdot \left | e^{-x}\right |=\left | e^{-x}\right | \Rightarrow                                    lim_{a \rightarrow \infty} e^{a(i\varepsilon -1)}=0$$ And similarly for $-a$. We have the integrals converging to $$\frac{-1}{i\varepsilon -1}+\frac{1}{i\varepsilon +1}=\frac{2}{1+\varepsilon^2}$$ Where does the factor of $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$ come from?

Comment: That is because there is a factor $1/\sqrt{2\pi}$ when computing Fourier transform.

Comment: This must be a different definition than the one I was taught. My inverse fourier has a factor of $\frac{1}{2\pi}$

Comment: It is just a matter of convention.

Comment: Ah thanks very much, this was making me extremely confused

Comment: There are different definitions, some folks use ${1 \over \sqrt{2 \pi}}$ to get some sort of symmetry between the transform and its inverse.

Comment: You're using a different definition of the FT from that of WA.  There is no standard definition.  Some write the FT with a positive exponent, while others use a negative one.  Some use a factor of $1$, while others use a factor of $\frac{1}{2\pi}$, while others still use a factor of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$

Comment: If there is no distinction between negative and positive exponents does this mean a result shown with a positive exponent holds with a negative exponent?

Answer (score 2):

Wolfram Alpha defines the Fourier transform of an integrable function as
$$
\hat{f}(\xi ) =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{-i\xi x} \, dx,
$$
while the inverse Fourier transform is taken to be
$$
\check{f}(\xi ) =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{i\xi x} \, dx.
$$
If you check your solution and multiply it by the factor $1/\sqrt{2\pi}$ you will obtain Wolfram Alpha's one. The reason why you don't get the same result is because you are using the following definition for the F. transform:
$$
\hat{f}(\xi ) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{-i\xi x} \, dx,
$$
but then you have to move the $1/\sqrt{2\pi}$ factor into the inverse transform, i.e.
$$
\check{f}(\xi ) =\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{i\xi x} \, dx.
$$
So, whatever definition you take, be careful because it will condition your inverse F. transform.

Comment: There is no "usually."  Some write the FT with a positive exponent, while others use a negative one.  Some use a factor of $1$, while others use a factor of $\frac{1}{2\pi}$, while others still use a factor of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$

Comment: Edited, thanks!

Comment: That looks great! +1  One more thing, you state that the OP used both definitions. I believe that he used one and WA uses the other.